# Our subversion server has a new IP address - now what?

Tags: svn

We connect to the repository by ip address - a quick hack introduced by the guy before me, since we don't have a *real* server, just an old pc running apache, svn etc. We recently moved offices and it seems the "server" is using DHCP - it booted to a new IP address this morning. Logging into trac (also running on that server) is easy: Just change the bookmark in the browser.

But what do I do about my working copy? How can I tell that where to find the server?

Comment: Not that you asked, but a spare Linux box set up with dnsmasq for DHCP relieves a lot of pain with DHCP and servers.  Unlike most DHCP setups, this server integrates DNS, so you can still refer to servers by name, even when they get re-IP'd.  Configuration is a lot easier than ISC DHCPD or BIND, as it re-uses things like /etc/hosts for IP to host name mappings.  I turned my DSL router's DHCP off at home, letting dnsmasq provide DHCP and DNS caching.  Good stuff.

Comment: If your admins can't setup the network so that you don't have to use naked IP addresses, then `/etc/hosts` is your friend.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Do an `svn switch` and use the `--relocate` option:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html

(or in TortoiseSVN, right-click -> TortoiseSVN -> Relocate...)

The relocate does not require repository access and is meant exactly for the case where the content is the exact same but the repository base is changed.

Comment: I'm getting an Error on the switch command: 'http://xxx.yyy.zzz.1/RepositoryName' is not the same repository as 'http://xxx.yyy.zzz.2/RepositoryName'. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: I'd suggest you also give the server a name in /etc/hosts and use that instead - at least if the IP changes again you won't have to reconfigure everything.

Comment: incredible_Honk: I used the TortoieSVN->Relocate method since I haven't got the CLI for SVN installed yet (though I normally prefer to do this stuff on the command line - somehow I find it soothing to be able to use the official SVN docs to get things right...)

Comment: I updated the link to the 1.5 version of the book.  Google likes returning results to the 1.0 version, which is massively out of date.

Comment: This is the right command, though when I first used it, I was prompted for my svn password.  As I had setup this password long, long ago, I had forgotten it.  In order to get the svn username/password navigate to your svn repositories passwd files: mine was in /home/svn/myrepo/conf/passwd and inside will be the username/password combos to use when prompted for the svn username/password

Answer (score 28):

Davs answer points to the right chapter, but to be more precise, its actually the command

> svn switch --relocate [old URL] [new URL]

which maps to the TortoiseSVN command TortoiseSVN -> Relocate

Answer (score 8):

Dav's answer (using `svn switch` with `--relocate`) is the proper answer, but before you do that, I have one other suggestion: Use a DNS name. Since it sounds like you don't have a DNS server, add an entry to your `hosts` file pointing to the IP address. Then if the IP address changes again, all you need to do is have each person update the hosts file on there machine.

Comment: Thanks. Will be looking into that when I next have time (i.e. the next time this happens...)

Answer (score 4):

Consider setting up DNS for the subversion server - you can use an internal DNS server, a free DNS hosting service, whatever. Doesn't mean the server has to be publicly accessible across the internet, you can have the DNS lookups return a LAN IP. That'll make it a lot less painful the next time the server changes IP.

When that part has been done, relocate the repository location like described in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want change SVN Repository URL address follow below steps

1. Go to the .svn folder location (may be it is hidden folder) of your
   repository OR Starting point of repository location
2. Right Click on Repository Folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Relocate.
3. Change the URL old to new.
4. Click Ok.